# Unity VR-Application - Can't import files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Right now I am developing a VR-application for my Oculus Go. In this Application i need to import files like images, video, audio during runtime. My Problem right now is that the import of these files do work in unity, but doesn't work on my oculus go.

In my project i use a file browser prefab from the asset store. this file browser can be opened during the runtime of my application, but when i want to open a file  for example an image, it only turns grey. the image should be loaded to a RawImage-Object.

[Filebrowser during runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHBuf.jpg)

[RawImage-Object turns grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQqBA.jpg)

[Unity-does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et84S.jpg)

I dont' understand why this is happening. I have to say I'm new to unity and would appreciate any kind of help! Here is the code of the image-load-script.

```
public class FileManager : MonoBehaviour {

public RawImage image;

public void OpenExplorer()
{
    SimpleFileBrowser.FileBrowser.SetFilters(true, ".txt", ".jpg", ".png", ".mp4");
    SimpleFileBrowser.FileBrowser.ShowLoadDialog( (path) => { UpdateImage(path); }, null, false, null, "Select File", "Select");
}

void UpdateImage(string pfad)
{
    if (pfad != null)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(pfad);
        image.texture = www.texture;
        var texWidth = www.texture.width;
        var texHeight = www.texture.height;

        if (texWidth > texHeight)
        {
            GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(1920/2, 1080/2);
        }
        if (texWidth < texHeight)
        {
            GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(1080/2, 1920/2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the path you're using?

Comment: the path is the file path which i choose through the filebrowser.

Comment: can you post the debug output of the path? If it's in the resources folder you may want to use `Resources.Load ("Images/SampleImage") as Texture2D;` instead of www

Comment: The output is:    D:\Dokumente\IMG_20180912_0002.jpg     It does show the correct path

Comment: And the pictures are not in the resource folder. I want to use pictures which i downloaded before with my oculus.

Comment: see if you get anything from `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
                Debug.Log(www.error);`, or put the www loading code in a try catch block and see what error it throws, or alternatively you could step through the www loading code with the debugger and check if www is loading the file.

Comment: @matze Did you ever get to try this answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

> My Problem right now is that the import of these files do work in
>   unity, but doesn't work on my oculus go.

Most buggy code work on the Editor but you will discover the issue with a code when you deploy or build the project.

Your problem is in the `UpdateImage` function:

```
WWW www = new WWW(pfad);
image.texture = www.texture;
...
```

You are supposed to yield or wait for the `WWW` request to finish before loading the image. The request asynchronous. Without yielding it, you would be trying to accessing incomplete image leading to a corrupted image or gray image depending on the platform.

Make the following changes:

**1**.Change the `UpdateImage` to a coroutine function (`void` to `IEnumerator`) then yield the `WWW` request with `yield return www;` before accessing the texture from it:

**2**.Call the `UpdateImage` function as a coroutine function with `StartCoroutine`:

Replace:

```
SimpleFileBrowser.FileBrowser.ShowLoadDialog( (path) => { UpdateImage(path); }, null, false, null, "Select File", "Select");
```

with

```
SimpleFileBrowser.FileBrowser.ShowLoadDialog( (path) => { StartCoroutine(UpdateImage(path)); }, null, false, null, "Select File", "Select");
```

**3**.Check for error before accessing the Texture. When the `WWW` request has finished, there could be an error. Check that before using the returned texture or item.

The final code should look like this:

```
public RawImage image;

public void OpenExplorer()
{
    SimpleFileBrowser.FileBrowser.SetFilters(true, ".txt", ".jpg", ".png", ".mp4");
    SimpleFileBrowser.FileBrowser.ShowLoadDialog((path) => { StartCoroutine(UpdateImage(path)); }, null, false, null, "Select File", "Select");
}

IEnumerator UpdateImage(string pfad)
{
    if (pfad != null)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(pfad);
        //WAIT UNTIL REQUEST IS DONE!
        yield return www;

        //Check for error
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            image.texture = www.texture;
            var texWidth = www.texture.width;
            var texHeight = www.texture.height;

            if (texWidth > texHeight)
            {
                GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(1920 / 2, 1080 / 2);
            }
            if (texWidth < texHeight)
            {
                GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(1080 / 2, 1920 / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think just calling image.texture.width and the same for height is better than calling www.texture, this generates a new texture 2d every time https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html

Comment: @palebone Yes, that's right. OP should use `image.texture.width`  after `image.texture = www.texture`  Although that has nothing to do with the issue.